# sequelize express table association/relation belongsTo

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js, associations

I have two tables, called employs and employ_detail.

I want to use a relationship between these two tables. I want to connect it using belongsTo. I've followed some tutorial but I am unable to do it.

Can anybody help me?

```
exports.getEmployee = function(req, res) {
    db.employs.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                models: db.employ_detail
            }
        ]
    })}
    .then(function(employs){
        const resObj = employs.map(function(employs) {

                //tidy up the employs data
                return Object.assign(
                    {},
                    {
                        id: employs.id,
                        name: employs.name,
                        department: employs.department,
                        salary: employs.salary.map(function(employ_detail) {

                            //tidy up the post data
                            return Object.assign(
                                {},
                                {
                                    id: employ_detail.id,
                                    emp_id: employ_detail.emp_id,
                                    name: employ_detail.name,
                                    phone: employ_detail.phone
                                }
                            )
                        })
            });
});
    res.json(resObj)
});
```

and this is my db.js file..

```
'use strict';
var Sequelize=require('sequelize');
var path=require('path');
var sequelize =new Sequelize('company', 'root', 'welcome123$', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});
const db = {};
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.employs = require(path.resolve('./models/employee'))(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.employ_detail = require(path.resolve('./models/employ_detail.js'))(sequelize, Sequelize);

//Relations
db.employ_detail.belongsTo(db.employs);
//db.employs.hasMany(db.staffs);

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need use options.

Example:

```
model.belongsTo(DIR.OrganizationModel, {
    foreignKey: 'organization_id',
    targetKey: 'organization_id',
    constraints: false,
});
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to.js~BelongsTo.html